# htop cgroup column widen

Tags: linux, cgroup, htop

How can I see full length of text `CGROUP` column in `htop`? I cannot enlarge it.

[image: htop-cgroup]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33269339/htop-process-viewer-set-column-width

In short, in current versions the column width is fixed. You can ask for this enhancement to the devs or implement it yourself :-)

You can use ps to find the processes in control groups you're interested in.